# inside divs move on minimizing width of screen

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html, sass

I am having troubles with the css on how to make my content within a div that has a border to stay inside and horizontal. when the columns run out of room with their content the columns and content move down. I want them to stay horizontal and readable still instead of moving down below.

Picture before minimizing screen width:
[image: before]

Picture after minimizing screen width:

[image: after]

As you can see the the content inside doesnt stay put!!

Here is my html and some css:

```html
<div class="container3" style="">
 <div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-11" style="min-width:760px;">
   <div class="panel panel-default" style="">
    
    <div class="panel-heading" >
     <div >
      <h style="margin-left:40px;">Your Requests </h>
     </div>
     
     <div style="float:right;margin-top:-30px;">Total: $<div id="sum" style="float:right;"> </div>
     
     </div>

    </div>
    
    <% @revisers.each do |reviser| %>
    <% reviser.reservations.where("status = ?", true).each do |reservation| %>

<script>
       
       var total = <%= reviser.reservations.where("status = ?", true).sum(:total) %>;
       $('#sum').html(total);
     
     </script>
    <div class="panel-body" style="">
     <div class="col-md-12" style="border:3px solid black;height:108px;max-height:108px;min-width:703px;overflow:hidden;">

      <!-- first column -->
      <div class="row" style="">


       <div class="col-sm-3 center" style="">
        <div style="margin-left:-45px;">
         <%= reservation.reviser.essay_type %>
        </div>
       </div>


       <div class="col-sm-2 center" >
        <div style=" margin-left:-40px;">
         File
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2 center" >
       <div style="margin-left:35px;">
        Due
       </div>
        
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2 center" >
       <div style="margin-left:70px;">
        File
       </div>
        

       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2 center" style="">
        <div style="margin-left:110px;">
         Total
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <!-- second column -->


      <div class="row" style="">
       <div class="col-sm-2" style="">
        <div style="margin-left:20px;">
         <%= render 'shared/essayicons', reviser: reservation.reviser %>
        </div>
       </div>


       <div class="col-sm-1" >
        <li class="thumbnail2" style=""><%= image_tag(reservation.user.avatar.url(:thumb), :id => "image-tag", class: "portrait") %></li>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1 center" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="row">
         <div style="color:green;margin-left:10px;">
          sent
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
         --->
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1">

        <li class="thumbnail2"><%= image_tag(reservation.reviser.user.avatar.url(:thumb), :id => "image-tag", class: "portrait") %></li>

       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2 center">
        <%= reservation.due_date %>

       </div>

       <div class="col-sm-1">
        <li class="thumbnail2"><%= image_tag(reservation.user.avatar.url(:thumb), :id => "image-tag", class: "portrait") %></li>

       </div>


       <div class="col-sm-1 center" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="row">
         <div style="color:green;margin-left:10px;">
          sent
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
         <---
        </div>

       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1">
        <li class="thumbnail2"><%= image_tag(reservation.reviser.user.avatar.url(:thumb), :id => "image-tag", class: "portrait") %></li>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1 center" style="margin-left:30px;">
        <h4>$<%= reservation.total %></h4>
       </div>

      </div>
      <!--  Third Column -->

      <div class="row" style="">
       <div class="col-sm-2 center">
       <div>
        <%= time_ago_in_words(reservation.created_at) %> ago
       </div>
        
       </div>


       <div class="col-sm-2 center" style="">
       <div style="margin-left:-45px;">
        <%= reservation.user.username %>
       </div>
        
       </div>

       <div class="col-sm-2 center">
       <div style="margin-left:-40px;">
        <%= reservation.reviser.user.username %>
       </div>
        
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2 center" >
       <div style="margin-left:70px;">
        <%= reservation.user.username %>
       </div>
        
       </div>

       <div class="col-sm-2 center" >
       <div style="margin-left:50px;">
        <%= reservation.reviser.user.username %>
       </div>
        
       </div>

      </div>





     </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>




   </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
```

SCSS file:

```css
.container3{
  margin:auto;
  width:80%;

}

.panel {
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.panel-default .panel-heading {
    color: #565a5c;
    background-color: #edefed;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;

}

.panel-heading{
  margin:0 auto;
  
  
  h1 {
    
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.panel-body{

  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

How can i get these `divs` to stop moving underneath each other? Just keep them put and if someone reduces screen width then they will just not be shown on screen unless the user extends the screen again, just like how the `total` on the header near `Your Requests` isn't showing up at a certain point when I minimize screen. Thank you!!^^

Comment: I guess you also got a CSS file, please post the contents of this file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.hidden-xs` and `.hidden-sm` to the offending `col-md-*` divs

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: I tried this but i think im doing this wrong... could you show an example of one of my rows in the black box?? Thank you ^^

Comment: Look at the chart on the Bootstrap docs, it shows you exactly how to use those classes. You can add .hidden* or .visible* to any element

Comment: I added .hidden-sm and .hidden-xs to the divs with the col-sm-2, col-sm-*, etc. still the same thing happens... I must be doing it wrong even though I read the link you sent ty btw for that link. But I must not be doing it right. I need an example because they don't show one. at least I didn't find an example!! thanks !!

Comment: should I make a table for it instead? does that work better? if you minimize the width of this screen that were on right now. You have to scroll right to find the rest of the page divs. I want my page to be more like that!!